# Hydrogen-One (HI) Image and R-band

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, hydrogen, infrared-radiation

In the paper below, on page 3, it says "In the lack of HI image, we use the r-band b/a ratio to correct for the inclination". Am I correct in thinking that what this means is that if we cannot measure the amount of neutral hydrogen in a galaxy, then measuring the amount of infrared light (in the R-band) coming from said galaxy will give us a good estimate for the amount of neutral hydrogen?

If this is correct, why can light from the R-band (wavelengths between 0.65-1.0 micrometers) be used to approximately determine the amount of neutral hydrogen, when the hydrogen line (HI line) corresponds to a wavelength of 21cm?

[Further evidence for a population of dark-matter-deficient dwarf galaxies](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00046)